# Issue with css triangle

Tags: css

I'm trying to make some triangles but it ain't working like I want to, look at this:

```
<th><a href="#">Rent</a> <div class="triangle-up"></div></th>
```

With this CSS:

```
.triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 6px 0 6px;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 6px 5px 6px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #FFF transparent;
    display: inline-flex;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #000000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #161717);
    height: 20px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, when using triangle-up it is not aligned with the text, which I want it to.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

How about adding `vertical-align: middle;` to both the triangle-up and triangle-down selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the tags you are using in incorrect. Since you are using `display:inline-flex` I am assuming you dont care about earlier ie versions.
The best way to vertically align something is 
`position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cb9my4sr/1/)